# How to insert huge volume of data into Neo4j

Tags: python, graph, neo4j, traceroute

I'm trying to insert into Neo4j data related to traceroute. I have about 55K unique nodes and traceroutes are about 80K. I'm using Python and neo4jrestclient to communicate with the db. File with traceroutes has the following syntax:

83.212.7.42;;83.212.7.41;;62.217.100.63;;83.97.88.69;;62.40.112.215;;62.40.98.150;;

My code is:

```
from neo4jrestclient.client import GraphDatabase
from neo4jrestclient import client


db = GraphDatabase("...")

node = db.labels.create("ipNode")



with open("traceroutes") as input:

for line in input:
    l= zip(line.split(';;'))
    i=len(l)
    try:
        prev=l[0][0]
        queryProbe = 'MERGE (a:ipNode7 {ip:"' + prev + '"})'
        db.query(queryProbe, returns=(client.Node, str, client.Node))
        for counter in range(1,i-1):
            next = l[counter][0]
            queryMergeNode = 'MERGE (b:ipNode7 {ip:"' + next + '"})'
            db.query(queryMergeNode, returns=(client.Node, str, client.Node))
            queryUpdateRelationship= 'MATCH (a:ipNode7 {ip:"' + prev + '"}),(b:ipNode7 {ip:"' + next + '"}) WHERE NOT (a)-[:precede]-(b) WITH a,b CREATE (a)-[:precede]->(b)'
            db.query(queryUpdateRelationship, returns=(client.Node, str, client.Node))
            prev=next
    except Exception:
         print "error"
```

The problem is that after getting 20K nodes correctly inserted, the insertion speed slows down quickly and I can not to put anything else.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a unique constraint on :ipNode7(ip)? If you don't, then the db is forced to run a label scan across all nodes with that label for those that have the given ip. The resulting behavior seems very similar to what you're encountering, insertion speed decreasing drastically as the number of nodes of that label increase.

Comment: Something like:
uq = 'CREATE CONSTRAINT ON (a:ipNode7) ASSERT a.ip IS UNIQUE'
    db.query(uq, returns=(client.Node, str, client.Node))
It's enough to put one time before with open("traceroutes") as input:?

Comment: I think it should be separate from your other queries, you only need to create the constraint once for db, then it will be used automatically for the lifetime of the db.